# R ggplot - plot multiple linear regresssion lines to a single plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression

I have 3 different linear regression models say -`lm1, lm2, lm3` which were created usig standard R `lm` like

```
lm1 = loess(df1$y ~ df1$x, span=0.10)
lm2 = loess(df2$y ~ df2$x, span=0.10)
lm3 = loess(df3$y ~ df3$x, span=0.10)
```

I want to get the fitted line for these 3 models into a single plot using `ggplot`. What would be the right way to do get a plot like below with a line for each model fitted with input data in the respective dataframes.

[image]

Comment: You can add a list to a `ggplot` object. That is, use `ggplot(aes(x, y)) + lapply(list_of_your_dfs, geom_smooth, ...)`. Please create a minimal working example, if you struggle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you X and Y variables the same for each df? If so, you could always rbind() your dfs and create another variable (e.g., df_source) and do something along the lines of this:

```
'''
ggplot(total_df, aes(x = xvar, y = yvar, color = df_source))+
    geom_jitter()+
    geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = F)
'''
```

Benefit of jitter for me is seeing the underlying distribution of data for each df or "condition".